# dplyr won't round but base-R will

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to round and I am able to using base R.

```
df$Variable99 <- round(df$Variable99, 2)
```

This is what I'm doing and it works great. The issue is: I originally tried piping everything with dplyr but got the weird error that is shown below.

```
df <- df %>% 
  round(Variable99, 2)
```

> Error in function_list[k] : object 'Variable99' not found

Variable99 is definitely an object in my data frame. It's about 10 steps to recreate the data frame. Is there enough information between my syntax and error to tell what's going on?

Comment: you need to add `mutate` there. `df %>% mutate(Variable = 
  round(Variable99, 2)`.

Comment: Won't mutate add a new column? I want to keep the same column "Variable99" and overwrite it with the rounded values.

Comment: So do `df %>% mutate(Variable99 = round(Variable99, 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the mutate command from dplyr (which is part of the tidyverse).  This allows you to create a new column, or to change a column in the data frame (or tibble).

I've provided an example below.

```r
suppressMessages(
  library(tidyverse)
  )
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.4.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.4.3

# Create a reproducible example
df <- tibble( Variable99 = rnorm(20) )

# Base R round
round(df$Variable99, 2)
#>  [1] -1.07  0.10 -1.66 -0.54 -0.76  1.19  0.76 -2.10  0.80  1.54  0.47
#> [12] -1.03  0.33 -0.45 -0.65  2.61 -0.60 -0.15 -2.52 -0.73

# Piping without mutate
df %>% 
  round(Variable99, 2)
#> Error in function_list[[k]](value): object 'Variable99' not found

# Piping with mutate
df %>%
  mutate(Variable99 = round(Variable99, 2))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 1
#>    Variable99
#>         <dbl>
#>  1     -1.07 
#>  2      0.100
#>  3     -1.66 
#>  4     -0.540
#>  5     -0.760
#>  6      1.19 
#>  7      0.760
#>  8     -2.10 
#>  9      0.800
#> 10      1.54 
#> 11      0.470
#> 12     -1.03 
#> 13      0.330
#> 14     -0.450
#> 15     -0.650
#> 16      2.61 
#> 17     -0.600
#> 18     -0.150
#> 19     -2.52 
#> 20     -0.730
```

Hopefully this helps!  There are some free lectures about the tidyverse over on datacamp which I've been recommending to some of my colleagues who are new to tidyversing (https://www.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-the-tidyverse).  Should hopefully be helpful!

(also, a small note: you will get more responses in future if you provide a reproducible example. It's much easier to do this using the reprex package. You can just write code, and then use an RStudio add-in to select it, execute it and get it into the right format as I did here - you can find the package here: https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex)